# Using multiple NOT IN in Firebird

Tags: sql, firebird

Table: ShareNumber

| ShareTypeCode | ShareNumber | StartDate | LastDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| stc1 | snA | 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-31 |
| stc1 | sn001 | 2021-01-01 | null |
| stc1 | sn002 | 2021-01-01 | null |
| stc1 | sn003 | 2021-01-01 | null |
| stc1 | sn004 | 2021-01-01 | null |
| stc1 | sn005 | 2021-01-01 | null |
| stc2 | sn001 | 2021-01-01 | null |
| stc2 | sn002 | 2021-01-01 | null |
| stc2 | sn003 | 2021-01-01 | null |
| stc2 | sn004 | 2021-01-01 | null |
| stc2 | sn005 | 2021-01-01 | null |

Table: ShareHolding

| ShareHolderCode | ShareTypeCode | ShareNumber | StartDate | LastDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| shc1 | stc1 | sn001 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-1-31 |
| shc1 | stc1 | sn002 | 2021-01-01 | null |

Table: ShareNumber

ShareTypeCode stc1 with ShareNumber snA   to sn005 was canceled.
ShareTypeCode stc1 with ShareNumber sn001 to sn005 are valid share number.
ShareTypeCode stc2 with ShareNumber sn001 to sn005 are valid share number.

Table: ShareHolding

ShareTypeCode stc1 with ShareNumber sn001 was sold to a shareholder and finally the shareholder exited and the company bought it back.
ShareTypeCode stc1 with ShareNumber sn002 was sold to a shareholder and the shareholder is still holding it.

SQL for valid shares:

```sql
select "ShareTypeCode", "ShareNumber" 
from "ShareHolding" 
where "LastDate" is null
```

Can you please help correct the following SQL statement if an investor would like to buy a share, ShareTypeCode stc1 with ShareNumber sn002?

```sql
SELECT "SN"."ShareTypeCode", "SN"."ShareNumber" 
FROM "ShareNumber" "SN" 
WHERE "SN"."LastDate" is null 
and "SN"."ShareTypeCode" = 'stc1' 
and "SN"."ShareNumber" = 'sn002' 
and "SN"."ShareTypeCode", "SN"."ShareNumber" not in ( select "SH"."ShareTypeCode", "SH"."ShareNumber" from "ShareHolding" "SH" where "SH"."LastDate" is null)
```

```
If found
   ShareTypeCode stc1 with ShareNumber sn002 is available for sale.
End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebird doesn't support row values, and if it did, the SQL standard syntax requires them to be enclosed in parentheses. That is, your query would then be `("SN.ShareTypeCode", "SN.ShareNumber") not in (...)`. However, as Firebird doesn't support this, this is a moot point.

Instead, you need to use a correlated subquery with `NOT EXISTS`:

```sql
SELECT "SN"."ShareTypeCode", "SN"."ShareNumber" 
FROM "ShareNumber" "SN" 
WHERE "SN"."LastDate" is null 
and "SN"."ShareTypeCode" = 'stc1' 
and "SN"."ShareNumber" = 'sn002' 
and not exists (
  select *
  from "ShareHolding" "SH" 
  where "SH"."LastDate" is null
  and "SN"."ShareTypeCode" = "SH"."ShareTypeCode"
  and "SN"."ShareNumber" = "SH"."ShareNumber"
)
```

Comment: `LibreOffice Base
The data content could not be loaded. /builddir/build/BUILD/libreoffice-7.1.6.2/connectivity/source/ commontools/dbtools.cxx:751 
firebird_sdbc error: 
*Dynamic SQL Error 
*SQL error code = -206 
*Column unknown 
*SH.LastDate 
*At line 1, column 227 
caused by 
'isc dsql prepare’ /builddir/build/BUILD/libreoffice-7.1.6.2/connectivity/source/drivers/firebird/Util.cxx:68`


Firebird doesn't use syntax like `"SH.LastDate"`.


I switched it to `"SH"."LastDate"` and it is ok.


Thank you so much for your assistance.

Comment: @Nukool I actually copied that from your original question (you had more columns with incorrect quotes there), and I corrected it afterwards, but I missed that one in my answer. I fixed it now.

Comment: @Nukool `where exists` and `where not exists` might work rather slow in Interbase/Firebird, as it might require target table row search-and-fetch for every candidate row in the query. Consider re-formulating it into `LEFT OUTER JOIN` with added `WHERE ... IS NULL` condition